# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI (spring 4.1 annotation configuration)

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-4

first of all, please don't lock this thread, please. I've read all the questions, and they still cannot solve my problem.
I'm studying how to use annotation on spring without configuring xml files.
I'm stucking with the error:

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/index.jsp] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

This is the project structure

[image]

This my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>spring-sample</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.M2</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is configuration class:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sample.spring")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class MainApp extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {

        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext
                = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(MainApp.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = sc.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet());
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registration.addMapping("/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver configureViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolve = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolve.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        viewResolve.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolve;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerMapping();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
        return new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is Controller:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }

}
```

index.jsp is inside WEB-INF folders, and there is nothing inside web.xml file. 
I think so far the configuration is correct because it can redirect to /WEB-INF/index.jsp.
However, I think that I'm missing some configuration to make the application to understand the path. (/WEB-INF/index.jsp)

Comment: Since you didn't provide the filestructure, are you sure WEB-INF is  in the right place?

Comment: What embedded container are you using? It seems  to be missing a JspServlet.

Comment: @The Head Rush: I've added the picture, I think it's in the right place

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: I run it using spring-boot through command the "mvn spring-boot:run"

Comment: Does that use tomcat or something else? Your `DispatcherServlet` should not be handling requests to JSPs.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: I'm not sure which one the spring-boot uses, but I think it's not tomcat. Why the DispatcherServlet should not be handling requests to JSPs?

Comment: Servlet containers have a dedicated (default) `Servlet` implementation for JSPs. This `JspServlet` performs the compilation and execution (invoking `service`) of the JSP. Spring's `DispatcherServlet` does not know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you're using Spring Boot, your configuration is far more complicated than it needs to be. Boot will automatically configure the `DispatcherServlet`, `ViewResolver`, `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, and `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` for you.

Take a look at [Spring Boot's JSP sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.1.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp) to see how little configuration you need.

In addition to removing pretty much all of the manual configuration, one key difference is that your main application class should extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` rather than implementing Spring's `WebApplicationInitializer` directly. Here's the equivalent class in the aforementioned sample:

```
package sample.jsp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class SampleWebJspApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SampleWebJspApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleWebJspApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The `main` method is used when launched the war file using `java -jar` and the `configure` method is used when the war is deployed to a separate Servlet container.

Also note the [sample's use of application.properties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/src/main/java/resources/application.properties) to configure the view prefix and suffix.