# Spring Boot jar cannot find index.html

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have Spring boot webapp running from jar. Spring boot for some reason cannot find `src/mai/webapp/index.html` and returns `There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.enable();
    }
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/pages");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have more logs ?

Comment: I am running Spring Boot from console and there is no log information.

Comment: Does it work if you don't customize the `ResourceHandlerRegistry` and just put the content to one of the default locations?

Comment: It works when `spring-boot:run Maven goal` but not in a JAR.

Comment: I removed `addResourceHandlers` and moved index to `src/mai/webapp/public/index.html` but same error

Comment: I take it that `src/mai/webapp` is a typo?

Comment: btw - I reckon this is probably a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566967/no-mapping-found-for-http-request-with-uri-web-inf-pages-mainpage-jsp-in-disp/27567879#27567879

Comment: @Steve, yes it should be `main`

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate. The other answer has a better explanation of the why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved problem by adding plugin

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
```