# Spring boot Could not resolve view with name

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Here's my spring boot configuration

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"org.app.genesis.client.controller","org.app.genesis.commons.service",
    "org.app.app.commons.security","org.app.genesis.inventory.service","org.app.genesis.client.auth"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.app.genesis.*.repo")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "org.app.genesis.*.model")
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter   {

    @Value("${driver.className}")
    private String DRIVER_CLASSNAME;

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String DB_URL;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String DB_USERNAME;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String DB_PASSWORD;

    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String HBM_DDLAUTO;

    @Value("${hibernate.packagesToScan}")
    private String PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;

    @Value("${hibernate.sql.dialect}")
    private String SQL_DIALECT;

    @Value("${hibernate.connection.pool_size}")
    private int CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE;

    @Value("${hibernate.format.sql}")
    private boolean FORMAT_SQL;

    @Value("${hibernate.multiTenancy}")
    private String HIBERNATE_MULTITENANCY;

    @Value("${hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver}")
    private String TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER;

    @Value("${hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider}")
    private String TENANT_IDENTIFIER_CONNECTION_PROVIDER;


    /**
     * Execution Point of our application
     *
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).run(args);
    }


    /**
     * HTTP Session Object scoped proxy for CheckOutCounter
     * that is used For storing items
     * temporarily for each user Session
     */
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session",proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public CheckOutCounter checkOutCounter(){
        return new CheckOutCounter();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a bean of a HttpRequestMappingHandler Adapter
     * @return HttpRequestMappingHandler
     */
    @Bean
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter(){
        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter = new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverterList = new ArrayList<>();
        messageConverterList.add(new org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        requestMappingHandlerAdapter.setMessageConverters(messageConverterList);
        return  requestMappingHandlerAdapter;
    }


    /**
     * Rest Template Configurations.
     */
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
        return new RestTemplate(httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(){
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory =
            new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

        httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(60000);
        httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(60000);
        return httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Data Source and Entity manager Configurations
     *
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource dataSource = new com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER_CLASSNAME);
        dataSource.setUsername(DB_USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(DB_URL);
        dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", FORMAT_SQL);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.multiTenancy", HIBERNATE_MULTITENANCY);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver", TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER);
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider", TENANT_IDENTIFIER_CONNECTION_PROVIDER);

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform(SQL_DIALECT);
        jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    /**
     *  Spring Security Configuration
     *
     */
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    protected static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("customAuthenticationProvider")
        private AuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider;

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
            auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);
        }


        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**"
                )
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN","CLERK")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/product/search", true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
        }
    }
}
```

here's a gist of my spring boot application.properties

```
#SPRING MVC
spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.view.suffix: .jsp
security.basic.enabled=false
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

The Controller that's being read

```
@Controller
public class ClientDashboardController  {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientDashboardController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/dashboard")
    public String displayDashboard() {

        Object principal =
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        return "dashboard";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/login")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Gist of my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And this is the error message

what did I configured wrong?

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1227) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:291) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
11:09:35.095 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
11:09:35.096 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
11:09:35.096 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered this error already. I believe you are extending the wrong class. check [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp/src/main/java/sample/jsp/SampleWebJspApplication.java) link

You need to extend your class to this `SpringBootServletInitializer`

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"org.app.genesis.client.controller","org.app.genesis.commons.service",
    "org.app.app.commons.security","org.app.genesis.inventory.service","org.app.genesis.client.auth"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.app.genesis.*.repo")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "org.app.genesis.*.model")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by adding dependencies, and here's a link to [Spring Boot Guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/):

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```